# SPI without CS pins configured (BeagleBone Black)

Tags: driver, beagleboneblack, gpio, spi, device-tree

I don't need to use the "stock" CS signals for SPI in BeagleBone Black.
Can I just omit their configuration in DTBO to save a couple of GPIOs?
In other words, (1) will SPI work properly? (2) may it cause a GPIO conflict?
Here is a DTS fragment example for SPI1:

```
....
fragment@0 {
    target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
    __overlay__ {
        /* default state has all gpios released and mode set to uart1 */
        bb_spi1_pins: pinmux_bb_spi1_pins {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <
                0x190 0x13  /* mcasp0_aclkx.spi1_sclk,  OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
                0x194 0x33  /* mcasp0_fsx.spi1_d0,      INPUT_PULLUP  | MODE3 */
                0x198 0x13  /* mcasp0_axr0.spi1_d1,     OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
            >;
        };
    };
};
....
```

Which kernel driver should I look into to verify? It looks that spidev.c is too high-level.

Thanks for directions!

Comment: When you are using the device tree, you are telling your drivers where the SPI pins are. If you do not define the (default) CS pin, your would normally explicitly redefine that as a GPIO pin (which the GPIO driver would control).

I am not familiar with the Beagle, but I have done this on a RedPitaya where the pins are defined both at FPGA and DeviceTree level (two levels!).

Comment: I'm afraid that the driver may use default (from its perspective) pins for CS0 and CS1, which may cause a conflict or interfere with other functionality.

Comment: The pin can be unconnected, so it doesn't matter which pin is used if the _pinmux_ is configured to use it for a different purpose. Thus I consider this solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pin can be unconnected, so it doesn't matter which pin is used if the *pinmux* is configured to use it for a different purpose. Thus I consider this solved – perfectly works here.

```
  fragment@0 {
  target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
    __overlay__ {
    . . . .
        bb_spi1_pins: pinmux_bb_spi1_pins {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <
                BONE_P9_31 (PIN_INPUT  | MUX_MODE3) // spi1_sclk
                BONE_P9_29 (PIN_INPUT  | MUX_MODE3) // spi1_d0 (miso)
                BONE_P9_30 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE3) // spi1_d1 (mosi)
                BONE_P9_28 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE7) // spi1_cs0
                // for spi1_cs0 it has to be MUX_MODE3, but since we want
                // to use it as a GPIO we set to MUX_MODE7, which
                // corresponds to GPIO3_14
            >;
        };
    . . . .
    }
  }
```

The code snippet above contains macros from Robert Nelson's overlays [collection](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/bb.org-overlays) and build suite.

Comment: You should post your updated Device Tree and accept your own answer.

Comment: I will post it tomorrow, however, I have no idea how I accept my own answer.

Comment: You should see a checkmark next to this answer. Click it.

Answer (score 0):

I just did that for one of the home projects i was working with, connected CS simply to ground, I could do this primarily because i do not have more than one slave on my SPI bus.